# How can I enable Q.E.D. mark at the end of proof using "svmono.cls"?

Tags: amsmath, sv-classes

Tomb stone (Q.E.D. mark) is not displayed at the end of a proof when I use "svmono.cls" for my dissertation. How can I enable it?

Here is the code example:

```
<\documentclass[12pt,sectrefs]{svmono}  
\usepackage{makeidx}        
\usepackage{graphicx}                              
\usepackage{multicol}        
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\makeindex             

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\mainmatter

\chapter{Chapter Heading}
\section{Section Heading}
\subsection{Subsection Heading}
\begin{theorem}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{theorem}
\begin{theorem}
  nonses\\
  nonsesnse\\
  nonsesnse\\
  nonsesnse\\
  nonsesnse\\
%nonsesnse\\
\end{theorem}


\begin{proof}
   here is the proof.
 \end{proof}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Because the `proof` environment in `svmono` is defined without the tombstone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `proof` environment provided by `svmono` does not include the automatic QED symbol. Instead it provides a clumsy method for manually adding a tombstone.

You can solve the issue by loading `amsthm`, so long as you continue to use `svmono` methods for defining new theorem-like environments.

```
\documentclass[12pt,sectrefs]{svmono}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\let\proof\relax\let\endproof\relax
\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter Heading}
\section{Section Heading}
\subsection{Subsection Heading}

\begin{theorem}
Some statement
\end{theorem}

\begin{proof}
Here is the proof.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a way to automatically add qed mark to the pre-defined proof environment in `svjour3` (`svmono` should be the same):

```
\documentclass{svjour3}
\smartqed
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtEndEnvironment{proof}{\phantom{}\qed} %Automatically add qed symbol to the end of proof environment

\begin{document}
    \begin{proof}
        xxxxxx
    \end{proof}    
\end{document}
```

The `\phantom{}` here is use to "exit" the vertical mode.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to add the following to the answer from Yijun Yuan. If you want to use \qedhere similar to how it works when used inside **unnumbered** math environments you can use:

```
\documentclass{svjour3}
\smartqed

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\global\newtoggle{QEDHERE} %Variable used to know if there is a command \qedhere before the end of proof
\AtEndEnvironment{proof}{\iftoggle{QEDHERE}{\global\togglefalse{QEDHERE}}{\phantom{}\qed}} %Automatically add qed symbol to the end of proof environment if there is no \qedhere
\newcommand{\qedhere}{\global\toggletrue{QEDHERE}\tag*{\qed}} %puts \qed and sets the toggle to keep track that it has been used

\begin{document}
    Normal proof:
    \begin{proof}
        xxxxxx
    \end{proof}    

    Proof with qedhere
    \begin{proof}
        xxxxxx
        \begin{align*}
             x=x \qedhere
        \end{align*}
    \end{proof}    
\end{document}
```

NOTE: It is very rudimentary and it may brake if you use \qedhere outside of a math or proof environment and it will produce two squares if you use it twice in the same proof, etc. so use it carefully.