# qed symbol missing in Springer document classes (llncs and svjour3)

Tags: environments, lncs

I'm currently using the two Springer document classes llncs and svjour3. Both define their own theorem environments (not using amsthm), including their own proof environment. However, this proof environment does not automatically generate a qed symbol (box) at the end of each proof, as the proof environment of amsthm does. What's the proper way of automatically generating a qed symbol while using the theorem/proof environments provided by the Springer document classes?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Just read [the manual](https://projects.mai.liu.se/BIT/usrguid3.pdf) of the `svjour3` class which tells you how to do it. The answer is the same for the `llncs` class. As a general rule, when using a class from an editor, just read the manual, it might answer a lot of the basic questions you might have.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. Of course, I already read through the manual. However, the manual only describes how to add the qed symbol manually at the end of a proof (using the \qed command). I'm looking for a way to do this automatically by using the \begin{proof} ... \end{proof} environment.

Comment: Then look at the answer of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/309259/how-can-i-enable-q-e-d-mark-at-the-end-of-proof-using-svmono-cls).

Comment: Thanks for the link to this question!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I enable Q.E.D. mark at the end of proof using "svmono.cls"?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/309259/how-can-i-enable-q-e-d-mark-at-the-end-of-proof-using-svmono-cls)